# pod not been updated, even though it shows an update available through 'pod outdated'

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods

I'm trying to update my pods, I list the pods updates through

> ```
> pod outdated
> ```

[image]

**podfile** ( Further more I have even tried to out `'Firebase/Auth', '6.3.1' in podfile` to specify the version but no use [**"-"** used in place of app, NDA -_- ] )

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
use_frameworks!
platform :ios, '9.0'


def extension_pod
#   pod 'ReadabilityKit', '0.7.1'
    pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 4.0'
    pod 'Firebase'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'FirebaseUI/Database'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'

end

target '-' do

extension_pod
pod 'LGSideMenuController'
pod 'Firebase/MLVision'
pod 'Firebase/MLVisionTextModel'
#pod 'FirebaseUI', '~> 5.0'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'TOCropViewController'
# [START google_pod]
pod 'GoogleSignIn', '4.1.2'
pod 'ARSLineProgress'
#pod 'TesseractOCRiOS', '4.0.0'
# [END google_pod]
pod 'TwitterKit'
pod 'DateTools'
pod 'Fabric'

  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for -

  target '-Tests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target '-UITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target '-E' do

      extension_pod

      end

end
```

Commands that I have done so far to update my `Firebase/Auth` repo,

- pod update 'Firebase'
- pod update 'Firebase/Auth'
- pod install --no-repo-update
- pod repo update && pod update 'Firebase/Auth'

All of these show as follow, but does not update to the specific version shown by `pod outdated`, am I missing some command for update process to occur?

```
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Pod installation complete! There are 17 dependencies from the Podfile and 33 total pods installed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another dependency requires `FirebaseAuth` to be a lower version.  See the `Podfile.lock` to get the details.

Note that you want to update the `FirebaseAuth` pod - not `Firebase/Auth` which is the `Auth` subspec in the `Firebase` pod.

It might be related to locking the `GoogleSignIn` pod to an old version.

Comment: yes you're right, Firebase/Auth depends upon other see [dependancies](https://cocoapods.org/pods/FirebaseAuth), I fixeded by `pod update` i.e. let cocoapods sort the dependent relevancy

Answer (score 0):

Change `platform :ios, '9.0'` to `platform :ios, '10.0'`